# bash, find nearest next value, forward and backward

Tags: bash, awk, find, asort

I have a data.txt file

```
1    2     3    4      5       6        7   
cat data.txt
13 245 1323 10.1111 10.2222 60.1111 60.22222
13 133 2325 11.2222 11.333  61.2222 61.3333
13 245 1323 12.3333 12.4444 62.3333 62.44444444
13 245 1323 13.4444 13.5555 63.4444 63.5555
```

Find next nearest: My target value is `11.6667` and it should find the nearest next value in `column 4` as `12.3333`

Find previous nearest: My target value is `62.9997` and it should find the nearest previous value in `column 6` as `62.3333`

I am able to find the next nearest (case 1) by

```
awk -v c=4 -v t=11.6667 '{a[NR]=$c}END{
        asort(a);d=a[NR]-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v = a[NR]
        for(i=NR-1;i>=1;i--){
                m=a[i]-t;m=m<0?-m:m
                if(m<d){
                    d=m;v=a[i]
                }
        }
        print v
}' f
12.3333
```

Any bash solution? for finding the previous nearest (case 2)?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131632/find-the-closest-value-from-target-value-both-forward-and-backward

Comment: bash is a UNIX shell. A shell is an environment from which to call tools, with a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX tool to parse text files is awk. You already have the right approach, re-writing the awk script in bash would be completely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ($fld > tgt) {
        del = $fld - tgt
        if ( (del < minGtDel) || (++gtHit == 1) ) {
            minGtDel = del
            minGtVal = $fld
        }
    }
    else if ($fld < tgt) {
        del = tgt - $fld
        if ( (del < minLtDel) || (++ltHit == 1) ) {
            minLtDel = del
            minLtVal = $fld
        }
    }
    else {
        minEqVal = $fld
    }
}
END {
    print (minGtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minGtVal)
    print (minLtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minLtVal)
    print (minEqVal == "" ? "NaN" : minEqVal)
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v fld=4 -v tgt=11.6667 -f tst.awk file
12.3333
11.2222
NaN

$ awk -v fld=6 -v tgt=62.9997 -f tst.awk file
63.4444
62.3333
NaN

$ awk -v fld=6 -v tgt=62.3333 -f tst.awk file
63.4444
61.2222
62.3333
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton. This work fine. And thanks for the tip above.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:

```
awk -v v1="11.6667" '$4>v1 {print $4;exit}' file
12.3333
```

And second part:

```
awk -v v2="62.9997" '$6>v2 {print p;exit} {p=$6}' file
62.3333
```

---

Both in one go:

```
awk -v v1="11.6667" -v v2="62.9997" '$4>v1 && !p1 {p1=$4} $6>v2 && !p2 {p2=p} {p=$6} END {print p1,p2}' file
12.3333 62.3333
```

Answer (score 0):

You solution looks unnecessarily complicated (storing a whole array and sorting it) and I think you would see the `bash` solution if you re-thought your `awk`.

In `awk` you can detect the first line with

```
FNR==1 {do something}
```

so on the first line, set a variable `BestYet` to the value in the column you are searching.

On subsequent lines, simply test if the value in the column you are checking is

```
a) less than your target AND 
b) greater than `BestYet`
```

if it is, update `BestYet`. At the end, print `BestYet`.

In `bash`, apply the same logic, but read each line into a bash array and use `${a[n]}` to get the n'th element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but this is what I came up with, not knowing `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFSBAK=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

best=

for line in `cat $1`; do
    IFS=$' \t'
    arr=($line)


    num=${arr[5]}
    [[ -z $best ]] && best=$num

    if [ $(bc <<< "$num < 62.997") -eq 1 ]; then 
        if [  $(bc <<< "$best < $num") -eq 1 ]; then
            best=$num
        fi
    fi

    IFS=$'\n'
done

IFS=$IFSBAK
echo $best
```

If you want, you can add the column and the input value `62.997` as paramters, I didn't to demonstrate that it would look for specifically what you want.

Edited to remove assumption that file is sorted.