# Numeric comparisons yielding incorrect result in awk

Tags: awk, numeric

I've recently found a script on the site :

[bash, find nearest next value, forward and backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822564/bash-find-nearest-next-value-forward-and-backward)

that is relatively old and requires 50 rep to comment on, which I do not have. I'm trying to get it to work, and don't know awk syntax very well, but I'm trying.  In the test file I'm using:

```
 -3.793  0.9804E+00  0.3000E+02
 -3.560  0.1924E-01  0.3000E+02
 -3.327  0.3051E-04  0.3000E+02
 -3.093  0.3567E-08  0.3000E+02
 -2.860  0.3765E-06  0.3000E+02
 -2.627  0.1119E-02  0.3000E+02
 -2.394  0.2520E+00  0.3006E+02
```

and Here's the script:

```
{
if ($fld > tgt) {
    del = $fld - tgt
    if ( (del < minGtDel) || (++gtHit == 1) ) {
        minGtDel = del
        minGtVal = $fld
    }
}
else if ($fld < tgt) {
    del = tgt - $fld
    if ( (del < minLtDel) || (++ltHit == 1) ) {
        minLtDel = del
        minLtVal = $fld
    }
}
else {
    minEqVal = $fld
}
}
END {
print (minGtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minGtVal)
print (minLtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minLtVal)
}
```

which, when run as so :

```
$ awk -v fld=1 -v tgt=-3 -f awk DOSCAR
```

produces:

```
 -2.860
 NaN
```

even though there is a lower bound, and I'm not quite sure how to fix it. The original post didn't have negative numbers in it, so they didn't have this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a pure awk script -- there's no bash in it at all, and the question should not have a `bash` tag. (Think about if someone asks "how do I do X in bash", and get an answer that uses python -- follow-up questions about that answer are python questions, not bash questions).

Comment: BTW, the question isn't written as well as might be ideal -- you should also show what your expected output is, and describe why the actual output is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a blank line in your input file, which is triggering a classic awk gotcha.

The core problem is the curious behaviour of awk's comparison operators, which do not require you to specify whether you want a numeric or a string comparison. (<opinion>This is precisely why automagical comparison operators are a bad idea.</opinion>)

In short, there are three scalar types in awk: numbers, strings, and "numeric strings". Literals in the program are either numbers or strings, and the result of arithmetic operators is always a number, while the result of a string concatenation is always a string. But the values you are comparing -- `$fld` and `tgt` -- are both potentially "numeric strings", because they come from user input.

A "numeric string" is a string which comes from user input, which happens to "look like" a number. On the whole, the definition of "looks like a number" is unsurprising, except for one detail: an empty string does not count.

If you compare two numbers, the comparison is numerical. If you compare two strings, the comparison is lexicographic. But if one (or both) of the things you are comparing is potentially a "numeric string", then the type of the comparison depends on whether the it is actually a "numeric string" or not. If it is a "numeric string", it gets turned into a number; otherwise, the other value gets turned into a string.

Consequently, if `$fld` is an empty string, then comparing it with `tgt` will be a string comparison rather than a numeric comparison. And the empty string is the smallest possible string for string comparison, so it will turn out to be smaller. However, when you then compute `$fld - tgt`, then `$fld` will be coerced into a number, and in this case the empty string turns into a 0.

So there are two possibilities. The simplest one is to force `$fld` to be changed to a number; this will at least be consistent:

```
{
    val = $fld + 0
    if (val > tgt) {
        del = val - tgt
        if ( (del < minGtDel) || (++gtHit == 1) ) {
            minGtDel = del
            minGtVal = val
        }
    }
    else if (val < tgt) {
        del = tgt - val
        if ( (del < minLtDel) || (++ltHit == 1) ) {
            minLtDel = del
            minLtVal = val
        }
    }
    else {
        minEqVal = val
    }  
}
END {
    print (minGtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minGtVal)
    print (minLtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minLtVal)
}
```

The other way is to eliminate lines where the indicated field cannot be a number. A simple and generally reliable test for numeric values is to compare the value with itself as coerced to a number:

```
(val = $fld + 0) == $fld {
    if (val > tgt) {
        del = val - tgt
        if ( (del < minGtDel) || (++gtHit == 1) ) {
            minGtDel = del
            minGtVal = val
        }
    }
    else if (val < tgt) {
        del = tgt - val
        if ( (del < minLtDel) || (++ltHit == 1) ) {
            minLtDel = del
            minLtVal = val
        }
    }
    else {
        minEqVal = val
    }  
}
END {
    print (minGtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minGtVal)
    print (minLtVal == "" ? "NaN" : minLtVal)
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The big test file I had did have a space at the end of it, good catch! Didn't realize that was how awk worked. +1